# Httpwebrequest returns different results over 3g/2g than WiFi

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have written an app which crawls a certain website for information.

Over WiFi or in my emulator it works perfectly.

I carry out a httpwebrequest, and read each line and put them into a list, I can then loop through this list and find the data I need.

However, when I try the same thing over 2G or 3G the web request return all the HTML in a single line, which breaks all my code.

Does anyone know why it is doing this or if there is anyway for me to get around this without rewriting most of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provider is most likely intercepting your request and removing all unnecessary characters from it, to speed up the internet connection and to produce less traffic. That is common practice. If this breaks your code, then you rather should identify why removing white-spaces and characters like this breaks your code.

There is nothing you can do about this. You should rewrite your code to be less restrictive.

Comment: Lazy coding I suppose. I will use an XDocument instead.

Comment: Yes, expecting white spaces and line breaks to be there is common bad practice. If my answer helps you, please feel free to mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: XDocument is a bad way to parse HTML Documents, because HTML is no valid XML. You should use the HTTP Agility Pack instead, which provides great ways to parse HTML.